# Inserting 4 Rows

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to insert one row when the cell is column 4 doesn't have the same value. For some reason it is inserting 4 rows. It only happens at the start. What could be wrong?

Thanks for your help!

```
If Cells(j, 4) <> Cells(j - 1, 4) Then
        Cells(j, 1).EntireRow.Insert
        j = j + 1
    End If
```

Comment: It may be inserting 4 rows because the next different columns are from the previously insertedrow. You should jump a line after the insert

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = lRow To 2 Step -1
            If .Cells(i, 4) <> Cells(i - 1, 4) Then .Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Insert
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

**ScreenShot:**

[image]